# Ionic Framework - Tab top on iOS Not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

We are new to Ionic and we trying to create page with two tabs one at top and another one is at bottom.

See below

[image]

In android, this two tabs are positioned correctly. However this is not working on iOS.

We are using tabs-top and tabs-bottom class to positioning the tab on top and bottom.

Please share your idea to help us.

Thanks
Nagarajan S

Answer (score 0):

Finally we got solution. In ionic.css  we are changed .tabs-top class style from top:0 to top:0 !important; its now working both on ios and android.

Thanks